# Radio button on click not working but works fine in fiddler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fire an event whenever a user clicks / declicks a radio button 
Searching on stack overflow and trying out my own example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXamScripts/tn0drjah/) works.

However the same thing in a MOzilla Browser version 31 or Google chrome it fails - not sure why 
I am using JQuery 2.1.1

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>formDemo.html</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8" />


<script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
<input id='r1' type='radio' class='rg' name="asdf"/>
<input id='r2' type='radio' class='rg' name="asdf"/>
<input id='r3' type='radio' class='rg' name="asdf"/>
<input id='r4' type='radio' class='rg' name="asdf"/>
</body>
<script>
alert("1");
$(".rg").change(function () {
    alert("yahoo");
});
alert("2");
$("#r1").change(function () {
    alert("yahoo");
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Check path of `jquery-2.1.1.min.js`

Comment: I tried it and for me it works. Press Str + Shift + K in Firefox, maybe there is a javascript error. Are sure jQuery is loaded?

Comment: Thanks - I had the jquery js file in the wrong location :( and as Rakesh and Raheel have mentioned - I needed to change the way the function was being called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your `jquery-2.1.1.min.js` path is wrong, check you path and include it. If you don't know the path or you have not downloaded the library then you can include like this :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Also put your jQuery code inside ready function like this :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".rg").change(function () {
        alert("yahoo");
    });

    $("#r1").change(function () {
        alert("yahoo");
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks - while the location was not the issue - placing the function inside document.ready did the trick and so did the solution mentioned by raheel

Answer (score 0):

Do you got any error in your console ?

If there is any error in your browser console post here

Try to put your code in `$(document).ready();`

Answer (score 0):

You are not making function in a proper way. Make it this way.

```
$(function(){
    $(".rg").change(function () {
        alert("yahoo");
    });
})

$(function(){
    $("#r1").change(function () {
        alert("yahoo");
    }); 
})
```

Comment: thanks this worked too - as Rakesh's answer came in earlier accepting his - but thanks for providing a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Change the script `src` and `link` `href` to following it will work fine:-

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: thanks - but that was not the issue - wrong js location and the way the function was called was the issue